# Buck converter with input network

Tags: buck, transient

I am trying to simulate a Buck converter for load transient with and without input filter for duty ratio of 0.5, as shown below in LT SPICE. The output voltage transient is almost same for both the cases. I am wondering why the input filter with significant RLC values is not making any impact on output voltage. I tried to play around different duty ratios and RLC values for the input filter but the two responses are always the same. Can you please help to understand why input filter components are not having any impact for the load transients?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why at zero supply?

Comment: Just want to observe output transient with respect to step change in load current so deactivated the supply.

Comment: Ah, so you're using a linearity argument. Can you prove that linearity applies to the given circuit and conditions?

Comment: Agree that it is a non linear circuit but I want to observe output impedance behavior so stimulating the circuit at the output without caring about input supply. Not able to understand why the input network doen't make any difference. Sorry if I am missing on anything.

Answer (score 1):

Testing transient response at zero supply voltage is using a linearity assumption.

That is, for a given input (say the step load current), we must have:
$$ v(t) = h(t) \star \left( a i_1(t) + b i_2(t) \right) = a h(t) \star i_1(t) + b h(t) \star i_2(t) $$
where \$h(t)\$ is the impulse response for the system, \$i_n(t)\$ are possible inputs, and \$a\$ and \$b\$ are any numbers.  (Here, the input is current and output is voltage, so \$h(t)\$ would be the self- or transfer impedance of the system.)

This condition will most obviously be violated for inputs that cause the body diode(s) to conduct.  The input shown, evidently drives 16V peak across the output; the voltage at the half-bridge isn't apparent, but even if it's a fairly small fraction of this, body diode forward-bias will occur.

The simple solution is to divide the input by a scale factor, so that the transient voltage is well below V<sub>F</sub>, restoring the linearity condition (for small \$a\$, \$b\$).  Then multiply the measured voltage transient by the same scale factor.

Or put supply voltage back in, which will also let you test nonlinear conditions, if that should be of interest.  (I'm guessing not, since the usual point of a buck converter is stable voltage, but there are applications where that might relevant.)

Or use a more linear (but more abstract or virtual) method, like SPICE switches instead of MOSFETs (but beware convergence issues with such abrupt switches, especially if you're going to be putting 1ps(!!) edges into them), or using a DC transformer (E/G source pair) instead of switching at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your external filter has a resonant freq of 9 kHz; Your output L.C is at about 2.6 kHz. Basically, the input filter isn't "seen" -- it's mostly the 33 uF input capacitance.

Note the ringing you do see is therefore mostly just the impulse response of the output L.C.

In this simulation you are not regulating the output -- just providing a fixed D%. If you add a regulator, and there's a (e.g. constant) load, then the DCDC input impedance will appear to be negative and you might then see severe ringing from that.